# MobileFirst 7.0 combining Authentication and Java SQL Adapter fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Im trying to combine [Java UserAdapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/js-sql-adapter/) and Adapter-based authentication

I want to get the users list after authenticated, but it fails

On server-side, Adapter-based authentication, `AuthenticationAdapter-impl.js`

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage) {
  errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

  return {
    authRequired: true,
    errorMessage: errorMessage
  };
}

function submitAuthentication(username, password){

  if (username==="admin" && password === "admin"){

    var userIdentity = {
      userId: username,
      displayName: username, 
      attributes: {
        foo: "bar"
      }
    };

    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);

    return { 
      authRequired: false 
    };
  }

  return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
}


function listUsers() {
  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/UserAdapter/", WLResourceRequest.GET);
  return resourceRequest.send();
}

function onLogout() {
  WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", null);
  WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

And on client-side,

```
function listUsers(){
  busyIndicator.show();
  var invocationData = {
    adapter : "AuthenticationAdapter",
    procedure: "listUsers",
    parameters: []
  };

  WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess: listUsersSuccess, 
    onFailure: listUsersFailure
  });
}

function listUsersSuccess(result){
  WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");
  busyIndicator.hide();
  WL.Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(result));
  if (result.responseJSON.length > 0){ 
    displayUsers(result.responseJSON);
  } else {
    listUsersFailure();
  }
}

function listUsersFailure(result){
  WL.Logger.error("Feed retrieve failure");
  busyIndicator.hide();
  WL.SimpleDialog.show("Banking Application", "Service not available. Try again later.", [
    {
      text : 'Reload',
      handler : WL.Client.reloadApp 
    },
    {
      text: 'Close',
      handler : function() {}
    }
  ]);
}
```

It returns `onFailure` response

[image]

Comment: Add the failure response? Add the authentication adapter implementation? add your challenge handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WLResourceRequest` is a client side API so you **CAN NOT** use it on an adapter since the adapter runs on the server.

You should update your `listUsers` function (client side) as follows:

```
function listUsers(){
  busyIndicator.show();

  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/UserAdapter/", WLResourceRequest.GET);

  resourceRequest.send().then(listUsersSuccess).fail(listUsersFailure);
}
```

**Update**

You can protect your Java Adapter methods by using the `@OAuthSecurity` annotation.

**UserAdapter.java**

```
@GET
@Path("/protectePath")
@OAuthSecurity(scope="YourRealm")
public String myProtectedMethod() {
    // your code here
    return "your-response";
}
```

Comment: is there any way to get the user list with authentication?

Comment: im trying to combine those 2 adapters, but java-sql adapter need to use WLResourceRequest

Comment: I tried to use  @OAuthSecurity, but it doesn't work, could you see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717407/mobilefirst-7-0-protecting-a-java-adapter-fails-with-custom-authenticator