# Mobilefirst 7.0 protecting a Java Adapter fails with Custom Authenticator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Im following and using the sample code  from [Custom Authenticator and Login Module](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/#intro) and UserAdapter from [Java SQL Adapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-sql-adapter/).

I want to get the user list after authenticated.

My configuring the `authenticationConfig.xml` file

```
<realms>
    <realm loginModule="CustomLoginModule" name="CustomAuthenticatorRealm">
        <className>com.mypackage.MyCustomAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>
</realms>

<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="CustomLoginModule">
        <className>com.mypackage.MyCustomLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
</loginModules>
```

My configuring the Java adapter, `UserAdapterResource.java` file

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")
public Response getAllUsers() throws SQLException{
    JSONArray results = new JSONArray();
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement getAllUsers = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");
    ResultSet data = getAllUsers.executeQuery();

    while(data.next()){
        JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
        item.put("userId", data.getString("userId"));
        item.put("firstName", data.getString("firstName"));
        item.put("lastName", data.getString("lastName"));
        item.put("password", data.getString("password"));

        results.add(item);
    }

    getAllUsers.close();
    con.close();

    return Response.ok(results).build();
}
```

But when I invoke the procedure above on client-side, it still return a response without authentication require, while it have to show a login module

Comment: Add the error response. Add the adapter implementation.

Comment: No error, it still return a respone with data from sql, with out authentication

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the app where it'd be expected for a login form to appear if clicking on add users.

Comment: I put OAuthSecurity(scope="myRealm") on GET, not on POST. I want to get the user list after logged in a form. But it still returns an exacly user list in my index.html page without authentication. I also want to authenticate other REST Call types, but i cant. Trying to combine example helps me understand more, and actually I need to do a project with authentication and sql for a worklight security thesis.

Comment: Hi Idan, could you take a look at my updated code https://www.dropbox.com/s/9g6tjitw49zr74h/LoginModule2.rar?dl=1

Answer (score 1):

From your code you only have a challenge handler for the `CustomAuthenticatorRealm` realm. Why not updated your adapter and protect it with that same realm instead of using `myRealm`.

Updated `UserAdapterResource.java` skeleton

```
@Path("/")
public class UserAdapterResource {
    // ... 

    @POST
    @OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")
    public Response createUser(@FormParam("userId") String userId, 
                                @FormParam("firstName") String firstName, 
                                @FormParam("lastName") String lastName, 
                                @FormParam("password") String password) 
                                        throws SQLException{
        // ...
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) throws SQLException{
        // ...
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")
    public Response getAllUsers() throws SQLException{
        // ...
    }

    // it's a good practice to protect this operation
    @PUT
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")
    public Response updateUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId, 
                                @FormParam("firstName") String firstName, 
                                @FormParam("lastName") String lastName, 
                                @FormParam("password") String password) 
                                        throws SQLException{
        // ...

    }

    // it's a good practice to protect this operation
    @DELETE
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")
    public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) throws SQLException {
        // ...
    }

}
```

With these changes, when the application launches it will show the login form to authenticate before showing the list of users.

**UPDATE:**

The Java Adapter protection is using OAuth and so the MobileFirst server issues a token for authentication. This token has a lifespan with an expiration. Logging out of a realm doesn't affect the token.

One way to implement this based on your needs is to decrease the TTL (time to live) of your token to something like 10 or 15 seconds (or whatever you want). You can do this by setting the `expirationInSeconds` attribute in your login module inside `authenticationConfig.xml`.

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
    <!-- token will expire 10 seconds after being issued -->
    <loginModule name="CustomLoginModule" expirationInSeconds="10">
        <className>com.mypackage.MyCustomLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
```

If 10 seconds have passed since the app connected to the server via adapter invocation or any other method then the user will need to reauthenticate.

Comment: I did exactly your answer , but it still shows the list of users, instead of showing the login form. My updated code https://www.dropbox.com/s/9g6tjitw49zr74h/LoginModule2.rar?dl=1

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this issue

Comment: @BraveWolf, we're not here to support your studies. This is a community and we'll answer when we can and not before that.

Comment: @Idan, I'm sorry about bothering all of you. I was too much anxious. I'm really sorry.

Comment: @YoelNunez, thanks so much for your supporting, but setting expirationInSeconds doesn't solve my issue. The app still doesn't require authentication. I tested your instruction with my above project code (dropbox link).